# AJAXControlToolkit - TabContainer not visible

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, mono, ajaxcontroltoolkit, monodevelop

I am using MonoDevelop on MacOS and I am having difficulty getting AjaxControlToolkit's TabContainer visible on Google Chrome. I even set the visible property to true for both the TabContainer and TabPanels but it still did not work. Here is the source HTML:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager  id="tsm1" runat="server" />

    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;">
       <img src="" />
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:200px;left:20px;">
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer id="NewTabContainer" runat="server" Height="300px" Visible="true" >
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel id="FirstPanel" runat="server" HeaderText="Tab 1" Visible="true" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                PAGE ONE - This is the first Panel.
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel id="SecondPanel" runat="server" HeaderText="Tab 2" Visible="true" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                PAGE TWO - This is the second Panel.
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
     </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

This is the HTML Chrome is generating:

```
<div id="NewTabContainer" class="ajax__tab_xp" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <div id="NewTabContainer_header">
        <span id="NewTabContainer_FirstPanel_tab"><span class="ajax__tab_outer"><span class="ajax__tab_inner"><span class="ajax__tab_tab" id="__tab_NewTabContainer_FirstPanel">Tab 1</span></span></span></span><span id="NewTabContainer_SecondPanel_tab"><span class="ajax__tab_outer"><span class="ajax__tab_inner"><span class="ajax__tab_tab" id="__tab_NewTabContainer_SecondPanel">Tab 2</span></span></span></span>
    </div><div id="NewTabContainer_body" style="height:300px;">
        <div id="NewTabContainer_FirstPanel" class="ajax__tab_panel">

                PAGE ONE - This is the first Panel.

        </div><div id="NewTabContainer_SecondPanel" class="ajax__tab_panel" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;">

                PAGE TWO - This is the second Panel.

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any idea where style="visibility:hidden;" is coming from? Have you tried overriding this CSS with FireBug or the inspector in Chrome to see if it displays?

Comment: I have no clue where it is coming from but when I remove it via the inspector it does show up though it does not function properly i.e. the tabs don't work when clicked.

Comment: can u tell me how you resolved this issue i am getting the same problem. My tabcontainer is visible on every browser except IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just copied the TabContainer from the AJAX site, I had the `OnClientActiveTabChanged` property set in my TabContainer without having a javascript function "ClientFunction" written. Once I removed this property, my tabs were visible and working. Of course, if you need this property, you'll need to write a javascript function to go along with it.

```
OnClientActiveTabChanged="ClientFunction"
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. In my case I had to change `asp:ScriptManager` to `ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager` and upgrade AjaxToolkit to the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me.

I was missing the runat="server" from the TabPanel tag.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue : the tab container wasn't visible although there are inside visible tabs.
I remarked that the first tab was hidden, and that it was the active tab.
Maybe the framework is "too smart" and concluded to hide the whole container...
So, to show the container, simply **set the ActiveTabIndex to an index of a tab that is visible**.
Bye.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same. The problem for me was that I was using a slider in one of the tabs and had not set the styling properly ie the RailCssClass, HandleCssClass and HandleImageUrl need to exist in the appropriate locations in your project.

If you run in Internet Explorer from Visual Studio you will get some extra error messages that the other browsers won't give.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so had the same issue, only needed to add AjaxFrameworkMode="Enabled" to the ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager.. hope this will help